# Angular - Open a link in new tab from component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm receiving a base64 PDF from an API REST.

This is the only way I found for decoding and downloading it:

```js
const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + apiResponse;
const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
const fileName = 'xx.pdf';
downloadLink.href = linkSource;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
```

It is working fine, but the PDF is being downloaded and I need it to be opened in a new tab instead.

Tried the following, but does not seem to work:

```js
window.open(linkSource, '_blank');`
```

How can I make `downloadLink` element to be opened on a new tab instead of downloading it? Need the `<a target="_blank">` behaviour.

Comment: I presume it's the browser "downloading" the new tab based on `data:application/pdf`. browsers don't have to be able to view pdf, so it just downloads it instead

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. Create a page which will receive a filename as parameter and that page should generate this HTML:

```
<embed src="xx.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can test this

```js
const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
const fileName = 'xx.pdf';
downloadLink.href = 'https://www.google.com';
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.target = "_blank";
downloadLink.click();
```